# Convert audio download with youtube-dl to flac?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

Is it possible to download a YouTube video as e.g. mp3 and then convert it to flac with ffmpeg? I can specify the arguments that ffmpeg shall use after the download with --postprocessor-args but I don't know how to get the file name there.

```
--postprocessor-args "-i downloadedfile.xxx -c:a flac downloadedfile.flac"
```

This would be the argument I want to use. Is this possible?

Comment: youtube-dl is open source. Why not try and add the conversion function in it ?

Comment: Forgot about that one haha. I might try it later today, but maybe it's possible without a modification

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Starting with youtube-dl 2017.03.16 - or [right now](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/commit/21bfcd3d6e41aed6113c874533fcfe41eb250d96) if you check out the git repository - you can simply pass in `--extract-audio --audio-format flac`, as in:

```
youtube-dl -x --audio-format flac  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc
```

<sup>(`-x` is short for `--extract-audio`.)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it immediately when I get home and mark the answer. I've done python so it would've taken me a while to get the hang of it I guess.

Comment: Since I don't know how to build my own version, I'm gonna wait this 10 days. Thanks again for your commit!

Comment: 2016.03.25 was just a conservative guess from me. youtube-dl 2017.03.16 - released just now - already contains flac support. See the [FAQ](https://yt-dl.org/update) if you need help updating.